# logrotate "postrotate" configuration

Tags: linux, logrotate

Below are 2 identical examples of logrotate configuration, the only difference is the `postroate` block where the second example is missing the `>/dev/null 2>&1 || true`

```
/var/log/nftables.log {
  size +10M
  maxage 30
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    /usr/bin/systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
  endscript
}

/var/log/nftables.log {
  size +10M
  maxage 30
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    /usr/bin/systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service
  endscript
}
```

I would like to know why is 2nd example bad (I assume it is) and please explain what exactly
`>/dev/null 2>&1 || true` does?

I mean the meaning of each of the characters: `>/dev/null` and `2>&1` and `||` and `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic `bash` syntax. You should read and reread `man bash` or any Linux Shell tutorial or book.

But, here goes:

`>/dev/null` redirects the STDOUT stream to the NULL (infinite data sink) device, throwing it away.

`2>&1` redirects the STDERR stream to STDOUT (which has been redirected to `/dev/null`).

`||` is the Logical OR operator. If (and only if) the expression to the LEFT of `||` fails (returns non-zero `$STATUS`), the expression to the RIGHT of `||` is evaluated and returned as the result of the whole expression.

`true` is a program that does nothing except return a SUCCESS `$STATUS`.

In summation, `/usr/bin/systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service >/dev/null 2>&1 || true` means:

Execute the command, discarding output and error messages. If the command succeeds, return SUCCESS. If
the command fails, return SUCCESS.

Beware: the `postrotate` commands are interpreted by `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`, so any bash extended features will not work.

Comment: If I understood correctly therefore if the expression on the left results in an error `STDERR` that will be printed somewhere? while `STDOUT` won't be, right?

Comment: @metablaster no, as the answer tells "2>&1 redirects the STDERR stream to STDOUT (which has been redirected to /dev/null).": both are redirected to /dev/null ie discarded.